# Printing from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, printing

I live in a remote area that has very good 3G and Edge coverage. I have bought and returned every other device but NOTHING seems to have reception to ANY Internet except for an iPhone.

I have the **HP B210 Photosmart All-In-One printer** that says: "print, anytime, anywhere," but it will not. While it printed from the iPhone while I set it up, once it was not on WiFi, it would not. It possibly would in an area that is readily 3G to all devices, it will not in my "remote, stubbornly unfriendly to all-but-iPhones area."

Is there a Bluetooth option? Is there an Apple type printer that has something like an iPhone receptor to the internet? Is there any hope?
Please help me. I need to be able to print. I have the app Print n Share ([iTunes link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/print-n-share-for-advanced/id301656026?mt=8)), but that assumes that I have an Internet connection

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Janice. To get good answers to your questions, I have a few tips. First, please remove as much 'rant' as possible from your question. Lines like "which assumes, like the rest of the universe, that all of mankind, has Internet easily available, as does every person I ask!!!!" are unnecessary. Also, some more details would be good. Exactly what is your setup when printing works? When it doesn't? Please use the `edit` link above to add to your post. See the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: My set up is this: no Internet available in my area except on an I-phone. So far, no other devise I have tried has been able to detect the 3-G/Edge that the I-phone can. Most cell phones, other than motorolas, do not work out here, including the I-phone, as a  phone, mostly as data.

Comment: 1. What is your printer connected to? 2. Do you have a wireless network of some sort in your house? 3. Do you have a wired network in your house? 4. Do you have internet service in your house via Cable, DSL or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Janice, you seem a little confused as to the distinction between a LAN (*local* area network) and the internet. A local network is essentially a bunch of devices interconnected, but not necessarily given access to the world wide web (hence the "local" moniker). Therefore, it doesn't matter if you live in a remote part of town or don't even have internet access. That's another, separate, process altogether.

To print wirelessly, you need to establish a connection with that printer. 3G/EDGE connects you to the cellular tower. This won't do because the cellular tower *doesn't* connect to your printer.

To connect wirelessly to your printer, you need to set up a LAN. This means getting a router ([AirPort Expresses actually have dedicated ports just for printers](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/features/printing.html)). LANs don't have anything to do with the internet (that's a modem's job). They link devices together, nothing more.

No matter which route you choose, you'll need to put that printer on a network (not the internet, unless you want to print from a far off location) and connect to that network using your phone.

As for wireless printing from your iPhone, you can use the AirPrint protocol. Unfortunately, due to licensing issues, it only supports a handful of printers. But that hasn't stopped some from expanding it's functionality. Check out [AirPrint Activator 2.0](http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/airprint-activator-v2-0/). It enables AirPrint on any printer and quite a simple product to use. Best of all, it is completely free.

Answer (score 1):

To use an AirPrint printer the iPhone/iPad/iPod needs to be connected to the same local network that the printer is connected to. The printer can be connected via wifi or an Ethernet connection that connects to your wifi network.

If the iOS device is connected via the phone mobile data network then it can't print to using AirPrint.

Why is your iPhone not connected to the wifi network? Is it because you are trying to print to the printer when away from home? Or is it because you have a large property and you are out of range of your wifi network?

While you can't use the native AirPrint when not connected to your home wifi, you can use  HP's ePrint service. This works by your printer having its own email address. You can email documents to the printer that it then prints.

The service is somewhat limited when compared to AirPrint, as you need to be able to get whatever you are printing into a document and be able to email it. So many apps that support AirPrint can't be printed from using ePrint.

Comment: The closest wifi network is 6 miles away

Comment: I really don't understand your setup then. You have the HP printer right and that is connected to your home network, right ? If so, you need to install a wifi router or wifi access point so your iPhone can connect to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Janice - you might possibly have luck getting an AirPrint printer to join your phone if you have personal hotspot enabled throughout your carrier, but it's a long shot and might not be worth a months charges to test.

Unfortunately, you'll likely have to get something like an airport express and any old USB printer. I did a little research in the [manuals for the B210](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DocumentIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&contentType=SupportManual&docIndexId=179166&prodSeriesId=4021933&prodTypeId=18972) and they make it clear you need a wireless router for AirPrint to work. You don't need an internet connection in addition to a network - just the network to let the printer talk to the phone as it was designed.

iOS/iPhone used to not know how to use 3G/EDGE for data when connected to WiFi. If you haven't updated to iOS 4.3.2 or so, you will have to download what you need to print on the data connection and then connect to WiFi just to print.

There isn't a Bluetooth printing option currently, nor printing from the 30 pin connector or the camera connector kit. It's not to say these can't be done, just that no-one has done the work on it.

Comment: I had previously tried the airport option, but it did not detect the 3-G/Edge that only my I-phone can detect.

Comment: My carrier makes me forego my data plan if I enable personal hotspot, so I haven't jumped to test that option for financial reasons. I do know AirPort express works as I have used it at a remote cabin often to print - joining the WiFi manually once I have the item to print all downloaded to the device.

Comment: The AirPort isn't designed to connect to 3G/Edge. It is design to connect to your home network and provide wifi service to your devices.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a Bluetooth option?

No.

> Is there an Apple type printer that has something like an iPhone receptor to the internet?

No.

You have two options:

Set up a wireless network in your home, and have BOTH the printer and the iPhone connect to that wireless network when you want to print.  For this to work you need a wireless router, and you need to be within 500 feet of the network with your phone.

Set up an internet connection for your printer - a 3G hotspot, DSL, cable modem, etc, and then configure a router so your printer can receive messages from Print n' Share.  You'll have to check out Print n' share's technical support and the printer's technical support to understand how to make this happen.

If you cannot be within 500 feet of your printer and wireless network when you want to print, and you can't get an internet connection at your house for your printer, you are not going to be able to print with your iPhone.

If you tell us more about what you are trying to do (where you are when you print, where your printer is when you print, whether your home has internet access or a wireless network, etc) then we can probably give you more precise information.